# Cannot build directx project on vs 2017, it cannot found the file 'D3D10.lib & D3DX10.lib'

Tags: c++, directx

I want to build up a DirectX project

but when I press build on vs 2017, it keeps showing

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'D3D10.lib & D3DX10.lib'
```

I google it but have no answer on it, what should I do?

spec list of my computer
Windows 11
VS 2017

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709469/d3dx11-lib-not-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [d3dx11.lib not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709469/d3dx11-lib-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2017 comes with the Windows 10 SDK. This includes DirectX headers, libs, and the shader compiler for Direct3D 9, Direct3D 10.x, Direct3D 11.x, and Direct3D 12.

`d3d10.lib` and `d3d10_1.lib` are in the Windows 8.x SDK and Windows 10 SDK.

The **D3DX** utility library (`d3dx9.lib`, `d3dx10.lib`, and `d3dx11.lib`) are *not* in the Windows SDK. This legacy DirectX SDK library has been deprecated and was not carried forward past the end-of-life for the DirectX SDK.

The primary recommendation here would be to use Direct3D 11 and *not* use Direct3D 10. There's no technical reason why you'd want to use Direct3D 10 (unless you had to support Windows Vista RTM or Windows Vista SP1). Direct3D 11 has much better utility support, tutorials, and hardware support.

If you really need to use the legacy D3DX9, D3DX10, or D3DX11 libraries for some reason, the best option is to use the [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/) NuGet Package. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/).

> While it is possible to configure your build to use the Windows SDK in VS 2017 with the legacy DirectX SDK, there are a lot of quirks and known issues there. It's best to just ignore that and use the NuGet package instead.

For more details see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) and [Living Without D3DX](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/)